# FullText search does not match Arabic Kaaf letter In Arabic mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, arabic, full-text-search

When I use full text in arabic language and search in table,
any record that contains arabic Kaaf letter (ك) does not appear in the result.

When I use full text in neutral mode I can search them!!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different Unicode chars for Arabic Kaaf, and depending on OS version and installed keyboard on users' station both might exist in your database.

U+0643 ك
U+06A9 ک

What I did to solve a similar issue was to write a small utility to convert all Kaafs to the same char. Then if you make sure your search input uses the correct char it should work. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @RollingCog.
But U+06A9 ک is a persian kaaf! 
when i type with persian keyboard its equal to U+06A9 ک .

Comment: That's correct. My bad :) However I suggest you pick one of the strings that does not show up in search and get the Unicode char code of the Kaaf in it (Sql UNICODE function) and compare it to char code of Kaaf in your search string.

Comment: I have a similar problem but in my case any word that contains the characters (ال) get ignored. I didn't try the neutral mode.